# mysql row not update properly in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I would like to upadte two columns with some data and to update data i have configured all necessary things.But i failed to update those data into my table by using codeigniter update command.

My ci code is

```
$result_data = array(
         [profileid] => 4
         [questionid] => 7
         [clientid] => 15
         [page_id] => 4
    );


$updated_data = array(
            [optionid] => 31,32,33,
            [option_score] => 1,2,3,
            [answer_given] => 1
        );

        $this->db->where($result_data);
       $this->db->update('tbl_result_temp', $updated_data);
```

When i am trying to update data through code the updation is not performing properly.
my table structure is as follows.
[my table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvBxV.png)

[table with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLkUD.png)

can any one please tell what is wrong?

Comment: Why [profileid], why not profileid?

Answer (score 0):

I found some error in your syntax(error in your array structure),

```
  $result_data = array(
         'profileid' => 4,
         'questionid' => 7,
         'clientid' => 15,
         'page_id' => 4
    );

$updated_data = array(
            'optionid' => '31,32,33',
            'option_score' => '1,2,3',
            'answer_given' => 1
        );

       $this->db->where($result_data)
            ->update('tbl_result_temp', $updated_data);
```

Comment: Let me know whether it's working or not? If it worked,please accept it as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use where_in:

```
    $result_data = array(
     [profileid] => 4
     [questionid] => 7
     [clientid] => 15
     [page_id] => 4
);


$updated_data = array(
        [optionid] => 31,32,33,
        [option_score] => 1,2,3,
        [answer_given] => 1
    );

$this->db->where_in($result_data);
$this->db->update('tbl_result_temp', $updated_data);
```